# io.netty.handler.ssl.StacklessSSLHandshakeException: Connection closed while SSL/TLS handshake was in progress

Tags: java, ssl, spring-webclient, spring-oauth2, reactor-netty

The idea is to create a WebClient bean with OAuth2 filter, which using bearer token, when running certain request to the file upload service.

The issue is, that locally everything works with same token-uri, but when the service is deployed in the cluster, i get such error.
After analyzing the issue it is obvious that it is not a certificate problem and not a proxy issue. Since i am able the correct certificate is being sent and also the connection to configuration of the oauth server is working. But when it comes to actual retrieval of the token, the ServerHello is being sent with the correct certificate without any response whatsoever.

Does anyone know how it may be resolved? Is it even the implementation issue on my side? Could it be an issue with closing sockets?

Here is the code examples:

```
    @Bean
WebClient webClientAuthorizedOAuth2(ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager) {
    var oauth2Client = new ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(authorizedClientManager);
    oauth2Client.setDefaultClientRegistrationId("saml");
    return WebClient.builder()
            .filter(oauth2Client)
            .build();
}

@Bean
public ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedReactiveOAuth2ClientManager(
        ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository) {

    ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider authorizedClientProvider =
            ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientProviderBuilder.builder()
                    .clientCredentials()
                    .refreshToken()
                    .build();

    var authorizedClientManager = new AuthorizedClientServiceReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(
            clientRegistrationRepository, new InMemoryReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientService(clientRegistrationRepository));
    authorizedClientManager.setAuthorizedClientProvider(authorizedClientProvider);

    return authorizedClientManager;
}

@Bean
ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository getRegistration(
        @Value("${spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.saml}") String registrationId,
        @Value("${spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.saml.token-uri}") String tokenUri,
        @Value("${spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.saml.client-id}") String clientId,
        @Value("${spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.saml.client-secret}") String clientSecret,
        @Value("${spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.saml.authorization-grant-type}") String authorizationGrandType,
        @Value("${spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.saml.client-authentication-method}") String clientAuthenticationMethod
) {
    ClientRegistration registration = ClientRegistration
            .withRegistrationId(registrationId)
            .tokenUri(tokenUri)
            .clientId(clientId)
            .clientSecret(clientSecret)
            .authorizationGrantType(new AuthorizationGrantType(authorizationGrandType))
            .clientAuthenticationMethod(new ClientAuthenticationMethod(clientAuthenticationMethod))
            .build();

    return new InMemoryReactiveClientRegistrationRepository(registration);
}
```

Here is the example of running the request to the resource server ->

```
webClient.post()
            .uri(url)
            .body(bodyInserter)
            .retrieve()
            .onStatus(HttpStatusCode::isError, ClientResponse::createException)
            .bodyToMono(DocumentResponse.class);
```

Unfortunately i am getting an SSL Handshake error

```
2023-09-25T08:57:06.825Z  WARN 1 --- [or-http-epoll-2] r.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect    : [bcb324a4, L:/1y.2xx.x.1xx:6xxxx - R:saml.xxx.com/1xx.1xx.xx.xx:443] The connection observed an error

io.netty.channel.unix.Errors$NativeIoException: recvAddress(..) failed: Connection reset by peer

javax.net.ssl|ALL|53|reactor-http-epoll-2|2023-09-25 08:57:06.837 UTC|SSLEngineImpl.java:825|Closing outbound of SSLEngine
javax.net.ssl|ALL|53|reactor-http-epoll-2|2023-09-25 08:57:06.837 UTC|SSLEngineImpl.java:786|Closing inbound of SSLEngine
2023-09-25T08:57:06.838Z  WARN 1 --- [or-http-epoll-2] r.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect    : [bcb324a4, L:/1x.2xx.x.1xxx:6xxxx ! R:saml.xxx.com/1xx.1xx.xx.xx:443] The connection observed an error

java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException: null
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.channelInactive(SslHandler.java:1150) ~[netty-handler-4.1.97.Final.jar!/:4.1.97.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:305) ~[netty-transport-4.1.97.Final.jar!/:4.1.97.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:281) ~[netty-transport-4.1.97.Final.jar!/:4.1.97.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:274) ~[netty-transport-4.1.97.Final.jar!/:4.1.97.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelInactive(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1405) ~[netty-transport-4.1.97.Final.jar!/:4.1.97.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:301) ~[netty-transport-4.1.97.Final.jar!/:4.1.97.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:281) ~[netty-transport-4.1.97.Final.jar!/:4.1.97.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelInactive(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:901) ~[netty-transport-4.1.97.Final.jar!/:4.1.97.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe$7.run(AbstractChannel.java:813) ~[netty-transport-4.1.97.Final.jar!/:4.1.97.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.runTask(AbstractEventExecutor.java:174) ~[netty-common-4.1.97.Final.jar!/:4.1.97.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:167) ~[netty-common-4.1.97.Final.jar!/:4.1.97.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:470) ~[netty-common-4.1.97.Final.jar!/:4.1.97.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:413) ~[netty-transport-classes-epoll-4.1.97.Final.jar!/:4.1.97.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997) ~[netty-common-4.1.97.Final.jar!/:4.1.97.Final]
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.97.Final.jar!/:4.1.97.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.97.Final.jar!/:4.1.97.Final]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
    Suppressed: io.netty.handler.ssl.StacklessSSLHandshakeException: Connection closed while SSL/TLS handshake was in progress
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.channelInactive(Unknown Source) ~[netty-handler-4.1.97.Final.jar!/:4.1.97.Final]
```

Thank you in advance!